# Latest order is not showing in admin sales order grid in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9

Latest order is not showing in admin grid, but it is saving in database and also showing order id in mail. i have cleared cache and tried with some solution but not getting success,please help me for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have overwritten the Order Grid page, try

1. Check with the log files for recent errors.
2. try disabling third party extensions related to this order grid.
3. Check by `<?php echo $collection->getSelect(); ?>` in the order grid page.